# Linux Bash - How to remove part of the filename of a file contained in folder

Tags: bash, replace, sed, find

I have several directories containing files whose names contain the name of the folder more other words.
Example:

```
one/berg - one.txt
two/tree - two.txt
three/water - three.txt
```

and I would like to remain so:

```
one/berg.txt
two/tree.txt
three/water.txt
```

I tried with the sed command, find command, for command, etc.
I fail has to find a way to get it.

Could you help me?. Thank you

Comment: Is the file path really `one / berg - one.txt`, or is it `one/berg - one.txt`?

Comment: [edit] your question and use the `{}` button to make your example legible.

Comment: Sí, ./uno/filename - uno.txt  - And I want to remove the directory name in the file name.

Comment: Do you want to remove everything between `<space>-` and the extension? Or **only** if it's the same as the directory name?

Comment: Only the directory name in filename.

Comment: @PacoRodriguez Does the directory name really include leading and trailing spaces?  Do all the file names really start with a leading space?

Comment: @John1024 I've asked him already and he said that there are no spaces there.

Comment: No. translator is a problem. There is no space at the beginning of the file name. only between '-'. I'm sorry but my English is lousy.

Comment: @PacoRodriguez In that case, why not update the question so that what you want is clear?

Comment: There is actually an edit of mine awaiting to be approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple, if you have GNU find:

```
find . -name '* - *.*' -execdir bash -c '
  for file; do
    ext=${file##*.}
    mv -- "$file" "${file%% - *}.${ext}"
  done
' _ {} +
```

---

- `-execdir` executes the given command within the directory where each set of files are found, so one doesn't need to worry about directory names.
- `for file; do` is a shorter way to write `for file in "$@"; do`.
- `${file##*.}` expands to the contents of `$file`, with everything up to and including the last `.` removed (thus, it expands to the file's extension).
- `"${varname%% - *}"` expands to the contents of the variable `varname`, with everything after `<space><dash><space>` removed from the end.
- In the idiom `-exec bash -c '...' _ {} +` (as with `-execdir`), the script passed to `bash -c` is run with `_` as `$0`, and all files found by `find` in the subsequent positions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with the help of sed:

```
#!/bin/bash

find -type f -print0 | \
    while IFS= read -r -d '' old_path; do
        new_path="$(echo "$old_path" | sed -e 's|/\([^/]\+\)/\([^/]\+\) - \1.\([^/.]\+\)$|/\1/\2.\3|')"
        if [[ $new_path != $old_path ]]; then
            echo mv -- "$old_path" "$new_path"
          # ^^^^ remove this "echo" to actually rename the files
        fi
    done
```

You must `cd` to the top level directory that contains all those files to do this. Also, it constains an `echo`, so it does not actually rename the files. Run it one to see if you like its output and if you do, remove the `echo` and run it again.

The basic idea is that we iterate over all files and for each file, we try to find if the file matches with the given pattern. If it does, we rename it. The pattern detects (and captures) the second last component of the path and also breaks up the last component of the path into 3 pieces: the prefix, the suffix (which must match with the previous path component), and the extension.

Comment: My biggest grump about this approach, by the way, is that it behaves badly with filenames containing newline literals -- which common UNIX filesystems do allow in practice, though POSIX doesn't require it. If one's going to be piping from `find`, better to use `-print0`, and correspondingly, `IFS= read -r -d '' old_path`.

Comment: El funcionamiento del script es correcto.
Eso era lo que buscaba. 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ("biggest" -- the other is calling `sed` in a loop, which is the kind of practice that gives shell its bigger-than-deserved reputation for being slow; we're taking fork+exec overhead to invoke `mv` no matter what, but this means an extra fork to spawn the subshell running `sed`, another `exec`, a FIFO being set up and then read from to read the subprocess's output, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right on both accounts. I addressed your first concern by updating my answer (I am always lazy to do it that way because I always forget the `-d ''` thing for `read`). As for the second one, in this case I like how the regex in `sed` provides stronger guarantees about the filename being renamed, which is why I would prefer that to a pure bash solution. I also like that this solution operates in `Θ(1)` memory.

Comment: With respect to "guarantees about the file being renamed" -- that's why the glob in my answer only matches files which are guaranteed to contain both the `<space><dash><space>` pattern, and following that, a dot -- both guarantees the later PEs rely on. You're right, though, that if careless about the guarantees involved in inputs passed through parameter expansion it's easy to have no replacements actually take place.

Comment: ...you're right, though, that if I didn't have the glob making such guarantees I'd need to do a comparison, similar to how your code does, or caution the user to expect `mv` to throw errors when a file doesn't need renaming. Even then, though, there'd be no need for `sed` -- one could simply compare `$file` to `${file%% - *}.$ext`.

Comment: I actually meant e.g. in `one/berg - one.txt` -> `one/berg.txt`, I check that the part remove (i.e. `<space>-<space>one`) is equal to `- $dir`, to avoid renaming misplaced/misnamed files.

Comment: Ahh. That could still be done without `sed` -- one could compare the relevant component to `${PWD##*/}`.